# Why isn't GPG adequate (is GnuPG better?) for Verifying Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, verification

I'd so much rather use GPG because GnuPG will require me to go into and type in the Terminal application. The last time I did that I killed my computer: I made it have a "fatal" system error. One wrong letter, space, dash, etc. - just one – and it's over, kaput. So I'm scared. And the guy in the tutorial does it so damn fast. So is it possible to use GPG tools to verify that I have the true Tor program and I'm really me, etc.? And avoid opening up the deathspace of Terminal?

Comment: GnuPG is the name of the software and `gpg` the name of the command-line program. You need to be more specific about the applications you are talking about.

Comment: I think you may be overstating the risk involved in typing commands into Terminal.